# What countries may be entered without visa by the holder of a Ghana refugee travel document?

Tags: visas, refugees, africa, ghana

What countries in the world may be entered without a visa by a refugee carrying a Ghana travel document such as the one illustrated?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What research have you done so far? Are you particularly interested in any specific destinations (narrowing the question down might help you get answers)?

Comment: I don’t know if this is relevant, but it might be an indication: a Ghanaian passport gives visa-free / visa on arrival entry to 64 countries and territories https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Ghanaian_citizens